# Understanding the date format 2019-10-16 02:37:08.000+000

Tags: java, datetime, timezone, utc, date

I am getting multiple date format in my data input
my requirement is to store these dates after converting to UTC.
some examples: 
2019-07-17T15:44:49+06:30 : i am able to convert this to UTC because +06:30 is timezone of the country where this date is logged.

I have another date format **2019-10-16 02:37:08.000+000**  . In this case i am not understanding what is the meaning of +000 can someone please explain more about this format. I did not get much information when i googled.

Comment: `+000` must be an error. It should be `+00`, `+0000` or `+00:00`.

Comment: It probably means data is *already* in UTC.  But as Ole said, three digits is probably an error.  At least, it's not ISO8601 compliant.

Answer (score 2):

I can see two possibilities when it comes to understanding `+000`.

1. It’s an error. It should have been one of `+00`, `+0000` and `+00:00`. Only the original publisher of the format can tell.
2. It’s a home-spun format. It probably means an offset of 0 from UTC. Possibly 0 hours 00 minutes from UTC, so one digit hours and two digit minutes of offset. But it’s a guess, again only the original publisher of the format can tell.

Java can handle option 2.:

```
    DateTimeFormatter formatter = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
            .append(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE)
            .appendLiteral(' ')
            .append(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_TIME)
            .appendOffset("+HMM", "+000")
            .toFormatter();

    String dateTimeInOtherFormat = "2019-10-16 02:37:08.000+000";

    OffsetDateTime dateTime = OffsetDateTime.parse(dateTimeInOtherFormat, formatter);
    System.out.println(dateTime);
```

Output from these lines is:

> 2019-10-16T02:37:08Z

**Link:** [Documentation of `DateTimeFormatterBuilder.appendOffset()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatterBuilder.html#appendOffset(java.lang.String,java.lang.String))